# Error when trying to split my assembly code up into multiple files

Tags: assembly, linker, gnu-assembler, superh

Trying to learn SuperH assembly with gnu assembler. I've been creating one file per subroutine, and then just doing a `.include` on each of those subroutine files in my main.s so effectively I've just been assembling just one giant .s file.

However, I'm now starting to run into some trouble. I recently tried to `.include` a new large subroutine into my main.s file, and now some of the previous subroutines I've written can't reach their constants. (`Error: pcrel too far`) It sounds like the displacement can only be 510 bytes.

I'm guessing `.include`ing everything into one big .s file is probably the wrong approach anyway.

So now I've tried splitting the constants out into each of these subroutine files like so:

```
.global my_subroutine

my_subroutine:
  mov.l important_address, r3
  mov.l important_const, r4

  <code omitted>

  rts
  nop

.align 4
important_address:   .long 0x00084000
important_const: .long 150
```

This way these variables are "close" to the code that uses them. I can assemble each of these subroutine files on their own, no issues there.

The trouble starts when I try to use any of these subroutines, ie:

```
.extern my_subroutine

test_my_subroutine:
    
# initialize parameters to test my subroutine:
    mov #20, r3                                   
    mov #50, r4                         
    mov #10, r5 

    bsr my_subroutine
    nop
```

(I realize `.extern` appears to be optional, ie: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_chapter/as_7.html#SEC89 but I included it just for the heck of it)

Even with this small chunk of code, trying to assemble it I get:

`Error: displacement to undefined symbol draw_pixel overflows 12-bit field`

What? I haven't even gotten to the linker yet. Isn't the linker supposed to figure out where all my subroutines should go, addresses, etc?

I then considered perhaps I was using the wrong type of branch. So I tried `bra` also, no luck.

Perhaps a 12 bit displacement style branch like bra or bsr won't work if I split my code up into multiple files. It seems like these will only work to branch within a single file.

Maybe the only way I can branch to external subroutines is with loading the address of my subroutine into a register and branching to that?

```
# initialize parameters to test my subroutine:
  mov #20, r3
  mov #50, r4
  mov #10, r5
                                               
  mov.l my_subroutine, r1
  bsrf r1
```

But now I'm back to this error: `Error: pcrel too far`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Strange, I'd expect the object-file format to have a relocation type for 12-bit relative displacements, with `bsr my_subroutine` using that.  So yes, I'd expect it to work unless they were actually too far away at link time.  But if the toolchain for SuperH doesn't support assembling 12-bit-relative references to unknown symbols, IDK if there's a workaround.